# Find the index of duplicated values in dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the duplicated values of dataframe column with counts but I need to find the index of particular duplicated value in whole column. **Look for the index of the sample dataframe as the index is not unique**

```
In[1]:
data = [['Center for epidemiological studies depression (CESD)','a'], ['Center for epidemiological studies depression (CESD)','b'], ['Social Causes of Depression','b'], ['Social Causes of Depression','b']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Column1','Column2'])
Out[2]:
print (df)
        Column1                                                   Column2
0     Center for epidemiological studies depression (CESD)          a
0     Social Causes of Depression                                   b
1     Center for epidemiological studies depression (CESD)          a
1     Social Causes of Depression                                   b
2     Depressive Realism                                            c
```

```
In[1]:
df_new = pd.DataFrame(df['Column1'].value_counts().values, index=df['Column1'].value_counts().index, columns=['Count'])
df_new.head()

Out[2]:
   Column1                                            Count
 Center for epidemiological studies depression (CESD)   2
 Social Causes of Depression                            2
 Depressive Realism                                     1
```

Here I got the duplicated values with column row but I also want the index of the particular duplicated reference but not able to get.

[Here is the original duplicated values of reference column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxQrL.jpg)

Moreover using `groupby` gives weird result. Here is the [actual original data values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiQxA.jpg) and what i get after [using `groupby` function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BU0Ze.jpg). Look at the data, the '0th' index is the first paper for which there are references in the reference column. **What I think since the index is not unique for reference column(original dataframe), the `groupby` is giving weird results.**

```
Expected output:
   Column1                                              index
0 Center for epidemiological studies depression (CESD)  [2][3]
1 Social Causes of Depression                           [1][4]
2 Depressive Realism                                    [5]
```

Comment: [dataframe.duplicated()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) does exactly as you described. "Return boolean Series denoting duplicate rows, optionally only considering certain columns." What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide the output you expect to see.

Comment: @ALollz Have you seen the original dataframe(link is given in the question)? I have mentioned that indexes are not unique because the reference column in original data has many values for particular column.

Comment: @piRSquared I hope it helped. but please look the original dataframe (https://imgur.com/QONxLNr) and all other links.

Comment: I think the links should be edited out. You've provided sample data in the question and since the links contain different data I think they only confuse and clutter the question. Also are you sure about the expected output, I think you may have swapped a few of the values?

Comment: @ALollz the dataframe values are huge in terms of adjusting here so i mentioned the sample dataframe but the format is same. The link has original dataframe, you can look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with pandas you can do like below.

You start with a DataFrame like this one :

```
data = [['Center for epidemiological studies depression (CESD)','a'], 
        ['Center for epidemiological studies depression (CESD)','b'], 
        ['Social Causes of Depression','b'], 
        ['Social Causes of Depression','b'], 
        ['Depressive Realism', 'c']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,
                  columns=['Column1','Column2'], 
                  index=[0,0,0,0,0])
```

You use **groupby** on your DataFrame but doing two reset_index before.

The first one ignore the current index and the second one creates a column with an index with 0, 1, 2, 3, ...

The column indexes will contain the position indices of the rows in the original DataFrame.

```
grouped = df.reset_index(drop=True).reset_index()\
            .groupby(['Column1'])['index'].apply(list).to_frame('indexes')
```

Output:

```
                                                   indexes
Column1                                                   
Center for epidemiological studies depression (...  [0, 1]
Depressive Realism                                     [4]
Social Causes of Depression                         [2, 3]
```

To add the count, you need to compute the len of the list for each row of indexes:

```
grouped['count'] = grouped['indexes'].map(len)
```

To order by "count" in descending order :

```
grouped = grouped.sort_values(by=['count'], ascending=False)
```

If you want to see the row corresponding to Social `Causes of Depression`, you can do :

```
df.iloc[[2, 3]]
```

Output:

```
                       Column1 Column2
0  Social Causes of Depression       b
0  Social Causes of Depression       b
```

Comment: I've detailed here why I do reset_index twice.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want the positions for each unique value in `'Column1'`.  When performing a `groupby`, Pandas tracks exactly those indices in the `groups` attribute.  However, you need to reset the index first.

```
grp = df.reset_index(drop=True).groupby('Column1')
print(grp.groups)

{
    'Center for epidemiological studies depression (CESD)':
        Int64Index([0, 2], dtype='int64'),
    'Depressive Realism':
        Int64Index([4], dtype='int64'),
    'Social Causes of Depression':
        Int64Index([1, 3], dtype='int64')
}
```

I'd make use of this and put it in a Series like this for pretty printing:

```
pd.Series(grp.groups)

Center for epidemiological studies depression (CESD)    Int64Index([0, 2], dtype='int64')
Depressive Realism                                         Int64Index([4], dtype='int64')
Social Causes of Depression                             Int64Index([1, 3], dtype='int64')
dtype: object
```

Alternatively, for the purposes of clarity, this also works:

```
pd.Series(range(len(df))).groupby(df.Column1.to_numpy()).apply(list)

Center for epidemiological studies depression (CESD)    [0, 2]
Depressive Realism                                         [4]
Social Causes of Depression                             [1, 3]
dtype: object
```

## _______________________________________________________

A simpler python answer

```
d = {}
for i, r in enumerate(df.Column1):
    d.setdefault(r, []).append(i)

print(d)

{
    'Center for epidemiological studies depression (CESD)': [0, 2],
    'Social Causes of Depression': [1, 3],
    'Depressive Realism': [4]
}
```

We can use `iloc` to get access to each row of a unique value from `'Column1'`

```
df.iloc[d['Center for epidemiological studies depression (CESD)']]

                                             Column1 Column2
0  Center for epidemiological studies depression ...       a
1  Center for epidemiological studies depression ...       a
```

Comment: Edited the question as you asked but this anwser won't help as groupby isn't working on non-unique indexes.

Comment: I've updated the answer.  Refresh the page.  I use `reset_index` to get a unique index.

Comment: I don't know what to make of that.

Comment: If it works on you example data but not on your real data then you haven't represented your real data well enough.  What is it about your real data that makes it different.